# How can I work on a python project hosted on a remote server using Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, remote-access

I have a server I connect to using SFTP, and I've followed [these steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/editing-individual-files-on-remote-hosts.html) to edit individual files hosted on the server.

But I have an entire python project structure on the server, and I'd like PyCharm's suggestions/auto-complete to be aware of the other files/directories in said project.

Is there anyway to achieve this using PyCharm? I feel like file mappings are the answer, but I don't see any way to download a remote directory onto a local drive and then setup a synchronization.

Also there are some resources I *don't* want to download onto my local environment, so if there was a way to do this remote only, so much the better.

Comment: I'm already able to edit a file directly on the server, but I'm not able to treat it as a "PyCharm Project".

Comment: Vscode Server is probably what you need instead.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I hope not, I've grown quite accustomed to the JetBrains Suite.